# user profile of other user shows up

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

The id of admin is **1** when i open the admin user at the admin panel. Likewise the id of `michael` is **2** but when i click the profile icon instead of showing me the profile of admin i get profile of `michael`. To get the id i have used `user.id` of the `requested user`.

Also the problem is i could not use slug in such model.

**restaurant/base.html**

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link user-icon" href="{% url 'userprofiles:profile' user.id %}">
          <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
{% else %}
```

**userprofiles/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'^profile/(?P<profile_name>[-\w]+)/(?P<profile_id>\d+)/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
    url(
        r'^profile/(?P<profile_id>\d+)/$', 
        views.profile, 
        name='profile'
    ),

]
```

**userprofiles/views.py**

```
def profile(request, profile_id):
    if profile_id is "0":
        userProfile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, pk=profile_id)
    else:
        userProfile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, pk=profile_id)
        user_restaurant = userProfile.restaurant.all()
        user_order = userProfile.order_history.all()
        total_purchase = 0
        for ur in user_order:
            total_purchase += ur.get_cost()
    return render(
                  request, 
                  'userprofiles/profile.html',
                  {
                   'userProfile':userProfile,
                   'user_restaurant':user_restaurant,
                   'user_order':user_order,
                   'total_purchase':total_purchase
                  }
           )
```

**userprofiles/profile.html**

```
{% for user_restaurant in user_restaurant %}
        {{user_restaurant.name}}<br/>
        {{user_restaurant.address }}
{% endfor %}
```

**userprofiles/models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    restaurant = models.ManyToManyField(Restaurant)
    order_history = models.ManyToManyField(OrderMenu)
    # favorites = models.ManyToManyField(Restaurant)
    is_owner = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.username

    # def get_absolute_url(self):
    #   return reverse('userprofiles:profile', kwargs={'slug':self.slug, 'id':self.id})
```

How can i use slug for such model so that in admin panel the slug for that user be automatically saved? Because there is no post method.

But the main problem is i am getting userprofile of another user.

Comment: If you make a third user with id=3, do you get Michael instead?

Comment: there are 3 user . One admin, one michael and another anonymous. If i do http://localhost:8000/userprofiles/profile/1/ i get user profile of michael and /2/ shows up user profile of anonymous and /3/ shows 404 error.

Comment: In the admin panel i checked the id of user admin is 1 and michael is 2 and anonymous is 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `1` everywhere you use `profile_id`

```
def profile(request, profile_id):
    if profile_id is "0": # Is profile_id a string or integer?
        userProfile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, pk=(profile_id+1)) # What does this do?
    else:
        userProfile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, pk=(profile_id+1))
        user_restaurant = userProfile.restaurant.all()
        user_order = userProfile.order_history.all()
        total_purchase = 0
        for ur in user_order:
            total_purchase += ur.get_cost()
    return render(request, 'userprofiles/profile.html', {'userProfile':userProfile, 
                                                        'user_restaurant':user_restaurant,
                                                        'user_order':user_order,
                                                        'total_purchase':total_purchase })
```

I suspect that somewhere in your code you've got a n-1 problem (i.e. computers start counting at 0 but humans start counting at 1). I haven't found exactly where it is, but this will probably work as a bandage solution in the meantime.

Also, I'm not sure what that `if` does in your code, it looks like it would never get used if `profile_id` is an integer.

Comment: What if i use slug instead of id? But i think if i used slug i have to use pre_save signal to save the slug in the name of user.username. Am i right?

Comment: Ok in that case you would create a slug field in your model and you can set the slug wherever you save an instance, you could do it in pre_save if you want. You would also have to make the url router pass slugs through to your view instead of integers.

Comment: I am posting my new solution in the answer but i am marking your answer as answered. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I used slug instead of id and for using slug i have used pre_save signal where slug value is taken from the username.

```
def profile(request, profile_slug):
    if profile_slug is None:
        userprofile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile,slug=profile_slug)
    else:
        userprofile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, slug=profile_slug)
        user_restaurant = userprofile.restaurant.all()
        user_order = userprofile.order_history.all()
        total_purchase = userprofile.total_purchase
    return render(request, 'userprofiles/profile.html', {'userprofile':userprofile, 
                                                        'user_restaurant':user_restaurant,
                                                        'user_order':user_order,
                                                        'total_purchase':total_purchase})
```

I filled the value of slug in this way.

```
def create_slug(instance, new_slug=None):
    print('instance',instance.user)
    slug = slugify(instance.user.username)
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
    qs = UserProfile.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by("-id")
    exists = qs.exists()
    if exists:
        new_slug = "%s-%s" %(slug, qs.first().id)
        return create_slug(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
    return slug


def pre_save_post_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = create_slug(instance)

from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
pre_save.connect(pre_save_post_receiver, sender=UserProfile)
```